# Excel cell value seems to be looping/duplicating

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Excel duplicating]

See image. The Formula Bar is showing "DESCRIPTON" for the selected cell. However, the selected cell shows duplication of this. How to resolve this? This happened after I executed a VBA code.

Comment: I am guessing, if you double click on the column with duplicate description, you will find newlines between the word "duplicate"

Comment: Drag the bottom of the formula bar down so you can see the other lines

Comment: Can we have your vba code in your question ?